# Probability of winning in the specific case

Tags: probability, game-theory

With 3 boxes, two of which are empty and one full, what is the probability of winning the full box by switching when there are two left? Considering that I initially choose one box, and then one empty box is opened.

Comment: This is the famous Monty Hall Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem ... a number of posts already on site address this issue in detail. Try a search. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monty+hall